# Persistent DB Connections aren't Getting Reused

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, mysql-connect, mysql-pconnect

I am using phpgacl library in one of my applications for authorization. This library is making connections to the database using mysql_pconnect. The problem is that the connections aren't getting reused and at times the whole application crashes down with error too many connections. 
I don't have too many concurrent users and hence increasing the max no of connections in mysql won't solve the problem permanently.
I did a simple test to simplify the problem. I wrote a simple php script `/var/www/a.php`:

```
<?
mysql_pconnect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
?>
```

When I hit `localhost/a.php` for the first time, I see one connection to the database in mysql processlist.
When I hit the link for the second time, I expect that connection to be reused. But, that's not the case. A new connection gets created and I see two connection in sleep state. The count increases every time I hit the link.

All these connections get closed when I restart apache.

I want to know how php mysql_pconnect works and how it uses previously made mysql connection. And, why is this not happening in the example I mentioned above?

One of the comments [here](http://php.net/manual/ro/features.persistent-connections.php) reads:

`You are probably using a multi-process web server such as Apache. Since
database connections cannot be shared among different processes a new
one is created if the request happen to come to a different web server
child process.`

Does this mean using mysql_pconnect with apache is not recommended?

Answer (score 0):

Every DB connection dies with the end of php process. So it's expected that persistent connections won't share with other web threads. 
`mysql_pconnect` can share DB connection only for application run time among different classes i.e.
The solutions to your problem are:

1. reduce timeouts for DB connections in MySQL config
2. close DB connections in your app
3. make own daemon for DB queries (but it's very complicated)